# How do I fix a "cannot open display" error when trying to install .bin program in Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, unix

**What I am trying to do:**

I have oracle OAM Docker container running on Ubuntu host. I want to install a patch for HTTP web gateway and see error,

```
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.  Actual unknown.   Failed <<<<
Some system prerequisite checks failed.
You must fulfill these requirements before continuing.
```

After a quick search I found the following [Question](https://k21academy.com/oracle-accesss-manager/solved-oracle-fusion-infrastructure-12c-installation-issue-display-at-least-256-colors-failed/) on Khan Acdamy.

When I run
`# echo $DISPLAY`
The out put is simply $DISPLAY
`#xhost +` return `xhost:  unable to open display "$DISPLAY"`
I have try to set the variable a follow other question on stackoverflow.

**What I have done so far:**

I have done the following.
recreate container with -e DISPLAY
Installed the xhost and xauth on docker container, as it was not per-installed
set SSH XForwarding on container but show  - `xauth bad display name` error
I installed SSH server and SSH-Clint on container.
In the client file of container /etc/ssh/ssh_config (comments removed).

```
Host *
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes 
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

In the server file /etc/ssh/sshd_config (My File is ).

```
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and may cause several
# problems.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none
```

On the server, I added to the file /etc/hosts.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
7.7.7.4   localhost        #my VM IP address 7.7.7.4 is a demo
153.70.79.45   devops-virtual-machine
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.20.0.2      283d474e2919
```

I didn't had `.Xauthority` file so I created it and restart the SSH connection and follow all the answer of [this Stack overflow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112217/ssh-xforwarding-fails-xauth-bad-display-name) question.

I have noting left to try but my problem is still there.

**Out put of my command.**
When I run .bin file see error
`Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.  Actual unknown.   Failed <<<<`

`xauth list`

No out put

xeyes
`Error: Can't open display: $DISPLAY`

Any help will be great. Please advice if my question is not clear as I am new to Stack instead of -ve mark.  Really Thanks.